# Banach-Zarecki theorem - who was Zarecki?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

I'm writing a paper for real analysis seminar, a paper about Banach-Zarecki theorem and I need some information about the authors.

Stefan Banach - there is no problem to find information about him.

What about Zarecki? 
I only found that he was russian mathematician, and in "Theory of functions of a real variable" Natanson writes "M. A. Zarecki".
This is all I know - I cannot find any information about this mathematician or his life.

Comment: Moisej Abramovitch Zaretsky (1903-1930) --- his short life explains likely why so little of him is known.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an excerpt from *Integration and Modern Analysis* by Benedetto and Czaja (pp. 202-203):

> *Moisej A. Zaretsky (1903–1930) is not a household name in mathematics, which is why we feature him now because of his beautiful result, independent of Banach, of the Banach–Zaretsky theorem (1925) (Theorem 4.6.2). Zaretsky was a Russian, and he died in the Caucasian resort of
>   Batumi. The English translation of the Russian Isidor P. Natanson’s text
>   uses the spelling “Zarecki”*

As a matter of fact, *Zarecki* is a Polish transliteration of his name -- most likely it was used by Banach and his group.

Comment: I guess he was born into a Jewish family living in the Pale of Settlement (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_of_Settlement), it might have well been Poland...

Comment: If you define 1900s Poland by its territory before partitioning it by Russia, Prussia and Austria then it is more than likely.

Answer (score 7):

You get more results searching under a different transliteration: "Moisej A. Zaretsky".